# Make assumption for function with variable argument

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, variable

I would like to assume that `a>t[b_]` for any `b`, such that e.g. `Simplify[a>t[c]]==True`. How could this be done? Simply including

```
$Assumptions = a > t[_]
```

does not work.

I only need to consider functions of one argument, e.g. `t[c]` rather than `t[c,d]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Assumptions = {Element[t[_], Reals], a > t[_]};

Simplify[a > t[c]]
```

> True

Comment: This solution works only partly, e.g.  Simplify[a > t[1]] yields True, but Simplify[a <t[1]] cannot be decided while it should give False.